# I'm looking for a word for a big change

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for a change, especially in a game.
Example

> The Bulls were winning but then there was a big ____ and they lost.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/revolution

Answer (score 2):

> **turnaround**.
>
> NOUN.
>   An abrupt or unexpected change, especially one that results in a more favourable situation.
>         *it was a remarkable turnaround in his fortunes*.
>   [...]
>   *All that changed however, with the turnaround at half-time*.
>   - [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/turnaround)

Answer (score 0):

The Bulls were winning but then there was a big **sea change**.  They lost.

**sea change**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sea+change)

2. A marked transformation: